# Как сделать, что бы шрифт подстраивался под размер блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Есть небольшой блок, у которого есть динамический контент. Проблема в том, что блок строго фиксированный, и текст не всегда хорошо выглядит. Как можно сделать, что бы шрифт уменьшался, если контент не помещается в блок? Думал сделать SVG, но текст там тоже имеет строго фиксированный размер. Насколько я понял, такое можно сделать еще с помощью canvas?

Comment: как вариант считать кол-во символов и в зависимости от этого задавать размер шрифта

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант считать кол-во символов и в зависимости от этого задавать размер шрифта, вывести примерную формулу для своих размера блока и шрифта, как пример, для блока 200 на 200 и здешнего шрифта примерно такая.

```js
var textLength;
$('.content').each(function( index ) {
  textLength = $(this).text().length;
  $(this).css('font-size', Math.sqrt(75400/textLength) + 'px');
});
```

```css
.content{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
I have related the substance of several conversations I had with my master during the greatest part of the time I had the honour to be in his service; but have, indeed, for brevity sake, omitted much more than is here set down. 
</div>
<div class="content">
I have related the substance of several conversations I had with my master during the greatest part of the time I had the honour.
</div>
<div class="content">
I have related the substance of several conversations I had with my master during the greatest part of the time I had the honour to be in his service; but have, indeed, for brevity sake, omitted much more than is here set down. They made signs for me to come down from the rock, and go towards the shore, which I accordingly did; and the flying island being raised to a convenient height, the verge directly over me, a chain was let down from the lowest gallery, with a seat fastened to the bottom, to which I fixed myself, and was drawn up by.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из ваиантов использовать @media запросы. 
Нажмите (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: и как это ему поможет?)

Answer (score 0):

Такую задачу можно решить с помощью метода [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Приведу простой пример:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent')
const content = document.getElementById('content')
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')
const submit = document.getElementById('submit')

// Получаем исходный размер шрифта
const originFontSize = parseInt(getComputedStyle(content, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'))

submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  content.innerHTML = textarea.value
  calc()
})

calc()

function calc() {
  const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect()
  let contentRect = content.getBoundingClientRect()
  let fontSize = originFontSize

  content.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px'

  while (parentRect.height < contentRect.height) {
    content.style.fontSize = --fontSize + 'px'
    contentRect = content.getBoundingClientRect()
  }
}
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="content">
    Но стремящиеся вытеснить традиционное производство, нанотехнологии подвергнуты целой серии независимых исследований.
  </div>
</div>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea><br>
<button id="submit">Применить</button>
```